# Why am I getting NaN values when web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am looking to scrape the player stats table from this website
https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/nhl/stats/2022-2023

My end goal is to have a data frame with all player stats from all leagues from 2007-2008 to 2022-2023. I believe I can do that (I can do all years in a league, and I am assuming all leagues will be the same process); however, I would also like to obtain the link to the individual page of each player, the season the stats come from, and the height and weight of each player (contained in the individual player page, and I am thinking the hardest part).

I will take help with any of the above; however, I am taking it one step at a time, and I am currently focused on obtaining the links for each player page. Below is the code that I am working with. I have tried to use various combinations of get, find, and find_all with different html elements, but I keep getting NaN values, and I am not sure how to correct the problem.

I have asked a similar question in the past; however, the code was above my knowledge level, and I am not sure it worked exactly right; however, I still very much appreciate any help. At the very least, it gives me ideas on what to research to improve my skills and knowledge.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

start_url = 'https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/nhl/stats/2023-2024'
r = requests.get(url=start_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", class_="table table-striped table-sortable player-stats highlight-stats season")

headers = table.find_all("th")

titles = []
for i in headers:
    title = i.text
    titles.append(title)


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=titles)

rows = table.find_all("tr")

for i in rows[1:]:
    data = i.find_all("td")
    row = [tr.text for tr in data]
    l = len(df)
    df.loc[l] = row


list = []
for link in table.find_all("span", class_ = "txt-blue"):
    list = link.get("href")
    df.loc[df.Player == name, "Player_URL"] = list


pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', 999)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', True)


df = df.replace(r'\n','', regex=True)
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)


print(df.to_string())
```

Comment: Where do you set the variable `name`?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, you're overwriting the built-in type name.

Comment: `NaN` is usually the result of numerical calculations. Everything in this code is strings.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues:

- You should clean up the player names *before* matching with the links.
- You were trying to get the `href` attribute of the *span* with class `txt-blue`. The span had no such attribute, so you get a None result that pandas converts to NaN. You want the *link* (`<a href=...>`) that's inside the span.
- You had an undeclared `name` variable that should have been extracted from the link.

```
df = df.replace(r'\n','', regex=True)
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)

for span in table.find_all("span", class_ = "txt-blue"):
    link = span.find('a')
    url = link.get("href")
    name = link.text
    df.loc[df.Player == name, "Player_URL"] = url
```

---

With these changes the NaN values are replaced with Player_URL:

```
        #                         Player                  Team  GP   G   A  TP   PPG  PIM  +/-                                                         Player_URL
0      1.           Nikita Kucherov (RW)   Tampa Bay Lightning  56  36  58  94  1.68   14    0        https://www.eliteprospects.com/player/77237/nikita-kucherov
1      2.        Nathan MacKinnon (C/RW)    Colorado Avalanche  56  33  58  91  1.63   34   14       https://www.eliteprospects.com/player/99204/nathan-mackinnon
2      3.             Connor McDavid (C)       Edmonton Oilers  50  21  62  83  1.66   26   23        https://www.eliteprospects.com/player/183442/connor-mcdavid
3      4.            David Pastrnak (RW)         Boston Bruins  56  35  45  80  1.43   43   20        https://www.eliteprospects.com/player/130383/david-pastrnak
4      5.            Artemi Panarin (LW)      New York Rangers  55  32  42  74  1.35   16    3         https://www.eliteprospects.com/player/24664/artemi-panarin
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
a_tag = link.find("a")
href = a_tag["href"]
```

to extract the link